# How to troubleshoot enabling API services in GCP using gcloud

Tags: api, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

When executing terraform apply, I get this error where I am being asked to enable IAM API for my project.

```
Error: Error creating service account: googleapi: Error 403: Identity and Access 
Management (IAM) API has not been used in project [PROJECT-NUMBER] before or it is 
disabled. Enable it by visiting 
https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/iam.googleapis.com/overview?
project=[PROJECT-NUMBER] then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few 
minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry., 
accessNotConfigured
```

When I attempt to enable it using gcloud, the service enable just hangs. Is there any way to get more information?

According to the [Google Dashboard](https://status.cloud.google.com/summary), everything is green.

I am also seeing the same issue using the UI.

```sh
$ gcloud services enable iam.googleapis.com container.googleapis.com
```

Error Message

```
ERROR: gcloud crashed (WaitException): last_result=True, last_retrial=178, time_passed_ms=1790337,time_to_wait=10000
```

Comment: I just tried the commands from my environment and it worked.  Can you try again?  Maybe it was transient?  Next, update your question with the output of gcloud info removing anything you consider sensitive.

Comment: Did the issue persisted after retrying? Where the comments mentioned by Kolban and DazWilkin enough to address your doubts?

Comment: This issue persisted after retrying. However, if i only attempt to enable a single API it worked. e.g. container.googleapis.com.

Comment: As well as Kolban I haven't been able to replicate the issue. If you have an exact reproduction case (with steps and Terraform config files included) open a case on the [Public Issue Tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#trackers-list) under the Cloud IAM component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `--log-http` to (any) `gcloud` command to get detailed logging of the underlying API calls. These may provide more details on where the error occurs.

You may wish to explicitly reference the project too: `--project=...`.

Does IAM need to be enabled? It's such a foundational service, I'm surprised anything would work if it weren't enabled.